# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: syncstatus (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name, syncstatus FROM names

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

There is an error in `sqlite` while opening app.

Logcat error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.simplifiedcoding.androidmysqlsync/net.simplifiedcoding.androidmysqlsync.OneMore.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: syncstatus (code   
1): , while compiling: SELECT name, syncstatus FROM names at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
```

`DbContact.java`

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.androidmysqlsync.OneMore;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 1/27/2017.
 */
public class DbContact  {

    public static final int SYNC_STATUS_OK = 0;
    public static final int SYNC_STATUS_FAILED = 1;


    //Constants for Database name, table name, and column item_view
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ddagroin_ddagro";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "names";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String SYNC_STATUS = "syncstatus";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";


}
```

`DbHelper.java`

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.androidmysqlsync.OneMore;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Priya on 2/27/2017.
 */

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //database version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "drop table if exists"+DbContact.TABLE_NAME;

    public DbHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DbContact.DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE=  "CREATE TABLE " + DbContact.TABLE_NAME
                + "(" + DbContact.COLUMN_ID +
                " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + DbContact.NAME +
                " VARCHAR, " + DbContact.SYNC_STATUS +
                " TINYINT);";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void saveToLocalDatabase(String name, int sync_status, SQLiteDatabase database){

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DbContact.NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(DbContact.SYNC_STATUS, sync_status);

        database.insert(DbContact.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);


    }

    public Cursor readFromLocalDatabase(SQLiteDatabase database){

        String[] projection = {DbContact.NAME, DbContact.SYNC_STATUS};

        return (database.query(DbContact.TABLE_NAME,projection,null,null,null,null,null));
    }



    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    EditText Name;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    RecyclerAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Contact> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    /*
    * this is the url to our webservice
    * make sure you are using the ip instead of localhost
    * it will not work if you are using localhost
    * */


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        Name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        layoutManager =new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        readFromLocalStorage();


    }
    public void submitName(View view){

        String name = Name.getText().toString();
        saveToLocalStorage(name);
        Name.setText("");
    }


    private void readFromLocalStorage() {

        arrayList.clear();
        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readFromLocalDatabase(database);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContact.NAME));
            int sync_status=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContact.SYNC_STATUS));

            arrayList.add(new Contact(name,sync_status));

        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        cursor.close();
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    private void saveToLocalStorage(String name){

        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        if(checkNetworkConnection()){



        }else {

            dbHelper.saveToLocalDatabase(name, DbContact.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED,database);

        }
        readFromLocalStorage();
        dbHelper.close();

    }
    public boolean checkNetworkConnection(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =(ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo!= null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }

}
```

Comment: Its clearly saying that there is no column of `syncstatus`

Comment: Use the terminal to check what exactly is getting created in the database. 1) adb shell
2) cd /data/data/<package.name>/databases
3) sqlite3 <dbname>
4) .tables

Comment: drop it and recreate it again.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me. may you have added that column and forgot to update the `DATABASE_VERSION` please update the database version and check.

give space after exists ":

```
public static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DbContact.TABLE_NAME;
```

Cursor entry
you have to select column first

```
String[] columns = {DbContact.NAME, DbContact.SYNC_STATUS};
Cursor cursor = db.query(yourtableName,
                    columns,
                    null,
                    null, null, null, null);
```

Then put your while loop

Comment: update DATABASE_VERSION.

Comment: private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.simplifiedcoding.androidmysqlsync/net.simplifiedcoding.androidmysqlsync.OneMore.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "existsnames": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: drop table if existsnames

Comment: thanks, an app is open but data is not saving in list view. see edit que.

Comment: see my edit and do the similar

Comment: public Cursor readFromLocalDatabase(SQLiteDatabase database){

        String[] projection = {DbContact.NAME, DbContact.SYNC_STATUS};

        return (database.query(DbContact.TABLE_NAME,projection,null,null,null,null,null));
    }

Comment: In my DbHelper.java

Comment: No, In your mainActivity,   readFromLocalStorage() method

Comment: still not working. I add your code.